# How to reduce the opacity of a background-blend-mode

Tags: html, css, background-blend-mode

Am looking for a way to reduce the opacity of background-blend-mode. The opacity in my code affects both the color and the image. I want it to affect only the blend mode. I want to achieve such an effect as in

[image]

```
.example {
    background-image: url(../assets/image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgb(77, 82, 86);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: background-color: rgb(77, 82, 86, 0.6);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the rgba function instead of rgb and opacity. The 4th parameter is the opacity ranging between 0 and 1. From your screenshot I assume you will need 0.9

```
.example {
    background-image: url(../assets/image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgba(77, 82, 86, 0.9);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ziale/pen/rNLEgNw)

Answer (score 1):

`background-blend-mode` is for blending multiple **background images** together or blend it with the background color.

on the other hand `opacity` is used to specifies the opacity/transparency of an element, including the element's background.

When you only want to lighten any **color** i.e. background-color, border-color, font-color you can go with RGBA or #AARRGGBB where **A** stands for alpha(transparency).

Try giving `background-color: rgba(77, 82, 86, 0 - 1);